# What's FORMAL Logic Notation? Logic Inference Problem too

Tags: logic, notation

Is this a proper example of FORMAL logic notation?
(Ǝ c ∈ Cookies such that Ǝ d ∈ duck, d wants c)

I have a question that requires an answer in 'formal' logic notation.  I'm assuming that they're making a distinction between 'normal' logic notation as in:  p ^ q -> r

Question 2:
I have a question that reads:

Use truth table to determine whether the following arguments are valid or not.
If (~p ∨ q ∨ r) holds and (q->r) holds, then infer that (p->r) holds. Here (~p ∨ q ∨ r) and (q ∨ r) are premises; (p->r) is the conclusion.

I'm not sure if the question is asking if (~p ∨ q ∨ r) ^ (q ∨ r) = (q->r)
If that's the case then the arguments are false.  At lease in the case of p=F, q=T, r=F.  Am I on the right path?

EDIT: 'COMMENT'

So the question is basically:
Given: (~p ∨ q ∨ r) ^ (q ∨ r) = (q->r) is this true?

Answer (score 0):

For 1., the "formal" notation, using *predicate* logic, will be :

> $(Ǝ c ∈ Cookies)(Ǝ d ∈ Ducks)Wants(d,c)$.

For 2., you have to show that :

> $(\lnot p ∨ q ∨ r) \land (q ∨ r) \vDash (q \to r)$,

i.e. the *conjunction* of the premises *logically implies* the *conclusion*. It does not means necessarily that premises and conlcusion are *logically equivalent* : in this case, as you noticed, they are not.